# Is there a way to set the ItemNumbered to increment i instead of numbers?

Tags: output-formatting, style

I am trying to get a cell style like the following:

```
 i)
 ii)
 iii)
```

instead of(if I can have both at the same time better):

```
 1.
 2.
 3.
```

I have checked the the stylesheet but it only has a counter with integers and the documentation is not helpful either. I've read the `CounterIncrements` option and the `CounterAssignmets` option but have not been able to understand if I can actually achieve the style I want with this.

Answer (score 2):

Change your style sheet to use the following `CellDingbat` for your "ItemNumbered" style:

```
Cell[
    TextData[{CounterBox["ItemNumbered", CounterFunction->RomanNumeral], ")"}], 
    FontWeight->Bold
]
```

For example, you could try:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["ItemNumbered"],
            CellDingbat->Cell[
                TextData[{CounterBox["ItemNumbered",CounterFunction->RomanNumeral],")"}],
                FontWeight->Bold
            ]
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]   
]
```

and then your "ItemNumbered" cells should use Roman numerals.

**Addendum**

If you just want to create a new cell style that just changes the "ItemNumbered" counter to roman numerals, you can use:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["ItemNumbered"],
            StyleKeyMapping->{"Backspace" -> "ItemRomanNumbered"}
        ],
        Cell[StyleData["ItemRomanNumbered", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["ItemNumbered"]],
            CounterIncrements->"ItemRomanNumbered",
            CellDingbat->Cell[
                TextData[{CounterBox["ItemRomanNumbered",CounterFunction->RomanNumeral],")"}],
                FontWeight->Bold
            ]
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]   
]
```

I added a style key mapping so that if you're in an "ItemNumbered" cell, hitting <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will convert the cell to an "ItemRomanNumbered" cell.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to have both, can I create a new style that extends the ItemNumbered so that I can keep both?

Comment: @martor Yes. What does keeping both look like?

Comment: I want to keep the ItemNumbered Style and create a new one (ItemRomanNumbered) that works the same as Item numbered except it counts in roman numbers.

Comment: forgot to tag. Sorry and thank you.